# Issue posting a PHP filtered array to an API

Tags: php, api, arraylist

Am working on a form whereby the data submitted the user am posting to an API via PHP curl. From the form, I have inputs that are controlled by a drop-down list where the user fills children details. It all works fine except that I need to post the inputs from the drop-down on the API which throws an error. The origin of the error is problem posting the filtered results from the array...

~ Please assist?

**Am array containing Children inputs from a dropdown**

```
 $a= [
    'child1'=>  isset($request->childDetail1Dob) ? $request->childDetail1Dob : null,
    'child2'=>  isset($request->childDetail2Dob) ? $request->childDetail2Dob : null,
    'child3'=>  isset($request->childDetail3Dob) ? $request->childDetail3Dob : null,
    'child4'=>  isset($request->childDetail4Dob) ? $request->childDetail4Dob : null,
    'child5'=>  isset($request->childDetail5Dob) ? $request->childDetail5Dob : null,
  ];
```

**Filter array to eliminate fields with null value**s

```
$b = array_filter($a, function($k) use ($a) { return $k!=null; });
```

**Data am trying to post**

```
 $data = array(
            'DobPrincipalTraveller' => "1992-02-05",
            'TravelStartDate' => "2018-11-23",
            'TravelEndDate' => "2018-11-30",
            'CoverOption' => "Grade 4",
            'DobOfSpouse' => "0000-00-00",
            'Children' => $b,
            'WithSpouse' => $request->spouse == null ?  '0' : '1'
        );
```

**Posts data to the API via POST**

```
 $travelplan = $this->global_Curl_Meta(
            $data, 'api/travel/get-plans')->data;
```

**Curl function**

```
public function global_Curl_Meta($data, $url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, (env('API_ENDPOINT_NGINX_IP') . '/' . $url));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    //Post and convert array to JSON
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE); 
    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

**Sample data required by the API**

```
{"DobPrincipalTraveller":"1978-01-22",
"TravelStartDate":"2018-11-22",
"TravelEndDate":"2018-11-25",
"CoverOption":"Standard",
"WithSpouse":"1",
"DobOfSpouse":"02-08-1979",
"Children":[
    {"DateOfBirth":"2015-05-23"},
    {"DateOfBirth":"2016-09-13"}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `$b = array_filter($a, function($k) use ($a) { return $k!=null; });`

use

```
$b = [];
foreach($a as $val){
    if($val){
        $b[]['DateOfBirth']  = $val;
    }
  }
```